# after image upload in form want to show a thumbnail of image

Tags: php, image, forms, file, upload

simple question this time around...

So I have this code I managed to find and it works well for me. But I would like to add to it a thumbnail display of the image upon submission. Could anyone help me to figure out the code and how it will fit in to display a thumbnail? Please and thanks everyone.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8mLt/) for it.

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">

File: <input type="file" name="file" style="width: 250px;"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

Comment: just make and <img> tag with attribute src="$link" where $link is the link to the image...

Comment: wow easy as that. but is there a way to style="" this thumbnail so it scales down appropriately, i.e. linking height and weight so it doesn't get distorted? Keep in mind the pictures uploaded will be anywhere up to 20 mb in size and very big, so input like 50% height won't do it for me, lol.

Comment: Just set the height to the desired height and leave the width empty; the width will scale automatically. The same goes when setting the width and leaving the height empty.
You can set the height and width in px, no need to make it in %, as long as you leave the other attribute empty

Comment: oh yea, I knew that, just didn't want to think anymore I guess, haha. Thank you very much ahmad, it works great. If you want put your first post as the answer and I will check it correct for ya. Thanks again

Comment: Done, and you are welcome ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make and `<img>` tag with attribute `src="$link"` where `$link` is the link to the image.

Comment: src="/images/<?php echo $file_name; ?>" this works fine too, thanks ahmad

Comment: oh yea, i always use php to output html, so i don't have to enter the damn php tags all the time. :D That's why i don't have the tags in the answer :P

Comment: actually one more itty bitty question, the broken image icon that comes up by default, any way to get rid of that?

Comment: You can use `file_exists()` to check if a file exists:

`if (file_exists("/images/$link")) {
    echo "<img src='/images/$link' />";
} else {
    echo "Image not found";
}`